# HTTP Live Streaming - How to do the encryption on Linux?

Tags: linux, apple, video-streaming, http-streaming

I am making some HTTP Live Streaming files (an Apple based way to segment video files so they can be 'streamed' by downloading specific chunks of a file ([more info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming))). It's possible to 'encrypt' each of the segments with a simple key, as a simple form of DRM. The Apple provided tools can do the encryption, but for various reasons I need to do this on Linux (Ubuntu). What tools/programmes can encrypt the HTTP Live Streaming Segments on Linux this way?

Comment: I do not get it. What is the goal? What do you really want to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on section 6.3.6 of the [draft submitted to the IETF](http://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-04#page-16), all you'd need to do is pass each file through AES-128-CBC, which can be easily done via a small web-facing script (PHP's passthru(), for example) and the "openssl" command-line interface to OpenSSL.

Actual level of sanity involved in attempting this, on the other hand, is still open for debate.  Especially since this adds exactly nothing to the security of your stream, unless I'm missing something terribly obvious in the spec.

Comment: If you control access the the encryption key (one small key file), then you can put your encrypted video files (lots of big files) somewhere insecure.

Comment: Ah, I see.  So push the files out to a CDN, but keep the key local (and protected by HTTP/401 or similar).  That makes me feel a little better about it, I suppose.